What is the difference between spring.rabbitmq.publisher-returns=true and spring.rabbitmq.template.mandatory=true?
What is the difference between spring.rabbitmq.publisher-returns=true and spring.rabbitmq.template.mandatory = true?
When one of these two configurations is set to true, when a message is sent to Exchange but cannot be routed to any queue then it will be returned to the producer. Why are there two configurations with the same functionality, or are there any differences between them that I don't know?


The logic there is like this:
        doSend(channel, exchange, routingKey, message,
                (RabbitTemplate.this.returnsCallback != null
                        || (correlationData != null && StringUtils.hasText(correlationData.getId())))
                        && isMandatoryFor(message),
                correlationData);

Where the returnsCallback is a global option for everything, and correlationData is per message.
For convenience, indeed that mandatory has to be set to true as well, but it still can be configured per message via RabbitTemplate.setMandatoryExpression(). So, even if there is a returns enabled, you still can control it per message. Unfortunately, there is no way to set that SpEL expression via Spring Boot configuration properties.
